# java.io.FileNotFoundException while submitting

Tags: java, apache-storm

I imported project have two files oov and config.properties files in the code the true path for both, but when I started to submit topology I got this exception:

This one in terminal when submitted topology

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (No such file or 
directory)
```

and this in the log file

```
2015-12-15 04:21:50 STDIO [INFO] java.io.FileNotFoundException: oov.txt   
(No such file or directory)
```

the code

```
FileInputStream finputstream = new FileInputStream(
                "/home/user/workspace/imported-project/config.properties");
```

and this whose coder wrote for oov

```
conf.put("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE", prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE"));
```

I changed it to

```
conf.put("/home/user/workspace/imported-project/oov.txt", prop.getProperty("/home/user/workspace/imported-project/oov.txt"));
```

but it didn't work.

However, I found when I submitted the topology content of config.propertied! How can it read it and throw exception in the same time ?

this project has file called config.properties contains like that

```
PATH_TO_QUERY_FILE=tweets.txt
PATH_TO_OOV_FILE=oov.txt

PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE=results.txt
```

,,,,, should i replace this paths with the real path i have or let them

Comment: I don't understand your last question... Can you rephrase it? If you try to read one the file, the worker executing your code will try to read locally. I assume you are running in a cluster; thus, you need to make sure that the file is available on **all** node in the cluster (because you don't know to which node Storm will schedule your code).

Comment: yes that's right i'm running on cluster but how can i check that i will be readen from aal node ? i've another question may  be help but i want to be sure . i will edited the post with additional information, i mean by last question when i submitted the topology it got the data in config.proprites like threshold and how mant tweets should recieved and so on but in the same time it throw excpetion so how it made two cases in the same time ?

Comment: You can not control (in a simple way) on which node an.operator will be executed. Thus, you should use a distributed file system (maybe HDFS) and read from there. For testing purpose and small files, copying the files to all nodes would also work. Not sure about the exception issue. Can you share your code?

Comment: of course i will edit now the post with code

Comment: I just had a look into https://github.com/mvogiatzis/first-stories-twitter/blob/master/src/main/java/trident/FirstStoryDetection.java -- there was some missunderstanding from my side before. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to load a client-local properties file. So specifying an absolute path for `FileInputStream` should work!

For the path of `oov.txt` you need to specify the path on the **worker machine in the cluster** (not a client-local path), ie, specify `PATH_TO_OOV_FILE=/use/woker/node/path/oov.txt` in your `config.properties` file. Then, `conf.put("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE", prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE"));` should work correctly.

*Of course, you need to make sure, that `/use/woker/node/path/oov.txt` exists on your worker node in the cluster that execute the topology.*

As an alternative, you can also specify it as `conf.put("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE", "/user/worker/node/path/oov.txt");` The fist parameter is the **key** and should not be changes -- only the value.

Furthermore, using

```
conf.put("/home/user/workspace/imported-project/oov.txt", prop.getProperty("/home/user/workspace/imported-project/oov.txt"));
```

does not make sense either. You need to specify a key for `conf.put(<key>,<value>)` and an key for `prop.getProperty(<key>)`. The key you use in `config.properties` is `PATH_TO_OOV_FILE`, thus you need to use it for `prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_OOV_FILE")`.

Comment: thanks i solved it but have another in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327617/supervsior-still-hasnt-start

Answer (score -1):

The directory `/home/user/workspace/imported-project/` won't be present in your deployment. Files used by an application should all be contained within the application as distributed.

Comment: Storm is not related to Web development... `web/...` would be very uncommon and it is absolutely no requirement.

Comment: thanks but where can i put in the right path i imported the project as the screen shot i'll edit in the post now , please take a look